# How to Learn JavaScript Correctly Quiz Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working through [How to Learn JavaScript Correctly](http://javascriptissexy.com/how-to-learn-javascript-properly/). About halfway through it has you create a quiz application. I'm able to get it to display the first question, then clicking the next button changes to the second question. But the problem is that when I click the button a third time, the screen clears and the third question never appears.

I'm sure I'm missing something easy. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

app.js:

```
var allQuestions = [
    {question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?", 
    choices: ["David Cameron", "Gordon Brown", "Winston Churchill", "Tony Blair"], 
    correctAnswer:0},
    {question: "Who is President of the United States?", 
    choices: ["George Bush", "Barack Obama", "Hilary Clinton"], 
    correctAnswer:1},
    {question: "What is the best state?", 
    choices: ["Iowa", "Wisconsin", "Colorado", "North Carolina"], 
    correctAnswer:1}
    ];

var score = 0;
var i = 0;


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next').addClass('hidden');

    nextQuestion();

});

function nextQuestion() {
    var container = $('#container');

    var questionName = allQuestions[i].question
    var answer = allQuestions[i].correctAnswer;
    var choice = 0;

    var question = "<div>" + questionName + "</div>";
    container.append(question + "<br>");
    var choices = allQuestions[i].choices;
    for (var j=0;j<choices.length;j++) {
        var choice = choices[j];
        var radio = "<input type='radio' data-choice='" + j + "' value='" + choice + "' name='" + allQuestions[i].question + "'>" + choices[j];
        container.append(radio + "<br>");
    }

    $('input:radio').on('click',function() {
        choice = $(this).data("choice");
        $('#next').removeClass('hidden');

    });

    $('#next').on('click',function() {
        $('#next').addClass('hidden');
        if (choice === answer) {
            alert("Winner!");
        }
        if (i < allQuestions.length) {
            i += 1;
        }
        container.empty();
        nextQuestion();

    });
}
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Survey</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.responsive.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/base.css">

</head>
<body>
   <!-- index.html -->
  <div id="container">



  <script src="js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/underscore-min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </div>
  <input type='submit' value='Next' id='next'>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the following code from withing the function; you're binding the events multiple times. At some time when you click `#next` once it may advance multiple time as it responds to the multiple binds.

```
$('input:radio').on('click',function() {
    choice = $(this).data("choice");
    $('#next').removeClass('hidden');

});

$('#next').on('click',function() {
    $('#next').addClass('hidden');
    if (choice === answer) {
        alert("Winner!");
    }
    if (i < allQuestions.length) {
        i += 1;
    }
    container.empty();
    nextQuestion();

});
```

Put the code inside a DOM ready event with the modification shown:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function() {
        choice = $(this).data("choice");
        $('#next').removeClass('hidden');

    });

    $('#next').on('click',function() {
        $('#next').addClass('hidden');
        if (choice === answer) {
            alert("Winner!");
        }
        if (i < allQuestions.length) {
            i += 1;
        }
        container.empty();
        nextQuestion();

    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't know you could double bind an event but that explains a lot :).